# 'New' Button is not visible for system admin for account object list view page

Tags: lightning, sfdc-styleguide

New button is not visible for system Admin profile in salesforce lightning but visible in classic version, on list view page.

Comment: As suggested in https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000peUrQAI  you might want to check if the "New' button is overridden by a Visualforce page which is not marked "Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app".

Answer (score 1):

Try using below step

Setup > Object Manager > (Object) > Search Layouts >
List View > Edit

Check the checkbox true for New [New]
and click Save

Reply if it does work.